# Как из двух функций js сделать одну?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код:

```
<script>
$('.form-control').on('change', function() {
let date = $(this).val();

$('#ever').text(date);
$('#datetimepicker3')

.data("DateTimePicker")
.minDate(moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
});


    var page_description = {
        has_flexmenu: 'cornered_dashboard',
        has_filters: true,
        has_datepicker: true,
        has_clip: true,
        contrpag: '',
        DPdata: {
            mindate: new Date('2020-12-13'),
            maxdate: new Date('2021-07-22'),
            datebegin: null,
            dateend: null,
            thisyear: new Date('2021-1-1'),
            prevyearbegin: new Date('2020-1-1'),
            prevyearend: new Date('2020-12-31')
        }
    };
</script>
```

Первая функция подтягивает динамически изменяемую дату из формы в minDate

Как данное значение ever из minDate подставить во второй minDate внутри DPdata?

Comment: тут только одна функция, вроде

Comment: Из нее мне нужно передать minDate в minDate внутри DPdata

Comment: Я могу вам подсказать, если только вы приведёте работающий пример кода

Comment: Работающий код только все запутает. Там форма с select полем, при выборе данных, дата автоматически изменяется, т.е. она рандомна. Данныя дата находится в функции из приведенного js. Т.е. функция подтягивает ее. Мне необходимо эту дату перенести в DPdata.

Comment: ну в моём случае, чтобы понять как это работат, мне нужно создать работающий пример и на нём протестировать. Но мне этого не хочется. Так что, ждите, если кто-то захочет это сделать)

Comment: Я подумал, что это просто, думал немного отредактировать функцию и все, ведь там все уже есть. Ошибся.

Comment: но ведь я могу не знать, работает это или нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.form-control').on('change', function () {
    let date = $(this).val();
    $('#ever').text(date);
    page_description.mindate = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    $('#datetimepicker3').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(page_description.mindate)
});

const page_description = {
    has_flexmenu  : 'cornered_dashboard',
    has_filters   : true,
    has_datepicker: true,
    has_clip      : true,
    contrpag      : '',
    DPdata        : {
        mindate      : new Date('2020-12-13'),
        maxdate      : new Date('2021-07-22'),
        datebegin    : null,
        dateend      : null,
        thisyear     : new Date('2021-1-1'),
        prevyearbegin: new Date('2020-1-1'),
        prevyearend  : new Date('2020-12-31')
    }
};
```

Comment: объявление переменной лучше вытащить наверх, думаю

Comment: Какая разница? На момент срабатывания события она будет уже объявлена. 

А вот от jquery в 2021 году уже можно избавляться.

Comment: Данные передаются из DPdata : { mindate : new Date('2020-12-13'), т.е. дата 2020-12-13 а не выбранная. Изначально именно 2020-12-13 должна изменяться. Пробовал закомментировать, не помогло https://i.gyazo.com/7a83484eddd019dc6b20e91a4cc1101b.png

Comment: Ну так выложите приер, который млжно запустить. Гадать на кофейной гуще тут никто не будет.